# Using ASP.NET MVC to populate images for JQuery bxSlider

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to show all the pics from folder to run in a flex slider dynamically.
This is the Code of

Model

```
public class ContentSliderViewModel
{
    public FileInfo[] ImagesList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ContentSliderViewModel model = new ContentSliderViewModel()
    {
        ImagesList = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images/2015-09-18/5")).GetFiles()
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    @foreach (var image in Model.ImagesList)
    {
        <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/2015-09-18/5" + image)" title="@image" /></li>
    }
</ul>
```

All the pictures have come into browser with their names but only picture icons are shown not the pictures
Please help me and tell what could be the problem with code..remember I made model without DbContext.

Comment: `image` is type of `FileInfo`. I'm assuming your want `image.Name` (or the property should be `public string[] ImagesList { get; set; }`)

Comment: Yeah, you could look at the source of the page to get a clearer view of what's actually being written for the `src` attribute.

Comment: Stephen Muecke I want Images with images names..can you please tell me your email id so that i can send you the screenshots of the real probelm.

Comment: @ShahrozAbbas (see how I start this comment). No I will not give you my email - that not how this site works. Look at the html your generating to understand your problem - your not generating the correct `scr` attribute.